# Highlighting words with TextKit selecting the wrong occurrence of repeated words

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, nsrange, textkit

I'm actually developing a Quran application in which I'm using TextKit to highlight verses and change their color. Everything is going great but I have a little problem with words that appear multiple times. First of all, my code is:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let attributedBackgroundColor = [ NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGray ]
    var myVerses = ["بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ","الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ","الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ","مَالِكِ يَوْمِ الدِّينِ","إِيَّاكَ نَعْبُدُ وَإِيَّاكَ نَسْتَعِينُ","اهدِنَا الصِّرَاطَ الْمُسْتَقِيمَ","صِرَاطَ الَّذِينَ أَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِمْ غَيْرِ الْمَغْضُوبِ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلاَ الضَّالِّينَ"]

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Vide initialement")
        string.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(25.0)), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.length))
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
        string.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.length))

        textView.attributedText = string
        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapRecognized))
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        textView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.isSelectable = false

        var str = ""

// Ajouter numérotation aux verses - Add numerotation to verses.
        for i in 0..<myVerses.count {
            if i > 0 {
                str += "("+"\(i)"+")"
            }
            str += String(myVerses[i])
        }
        print(str)
        textView.text = str + "("+"\(myVerses.count)"+")"
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


   // Sélection des verses - Select Verses
    func tapRecognized(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if recognizer.state == .recognized {
            let point = recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)
            let detectedText = self.getWordAtPosition(pos: point, in: textView)
            if (detectedText != "") {
                print("detectedText  == \(detectedText)")
                let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.textView.text)
                let verses = self.textView.text.components(separatedBy: ")")



                if let detectedRange = textView.text.range(of: detectedText) {
                    let startPosOfSubstring = textView.text.distance(from: textView.text.startIndex, to: detectedRange.lowerBound)
                    let detectedLength = detectedText.characters.count
               let rangeOfSub = (startPosOfSubstring,detectedLength)
               print("-- rangeofSub == " ,rangeOfSub)
                    let rangeOfSubstring = NSRange(location: startPosOfSubstring, length: detectedLength)


                    for verse: String in verses {
                        if let detectedVerse = textView.text.range(of: verse) {
                            let startPosOfVerse = textView.text.distance(from: textView.text.startIndex, to: detectedVerse.lowerBound)
                            let detectedLengthOfVerse = verse.characters.count

                            let tupleVerse = (startPosOfVerse,detectedLengthOfVerse)
                            print("++ rangeofVerse == " ,tupleVerse)
                            let rangeOfVerse = NSRange(location: startPosOfVerse, length: detectedLengthOfVerse)
                            print(verse)


                            let range = (self.textView.text as NSString).range(of: verse)
                            let contained = NSLocationInRange(rangeOfSubstring.location, rangeOfVerse)
                            if (contained) {
                                print ("************************************")
                            print("contained is :" ,contained)
                                print ("************************************")

                                string.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: range)
                                string.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.darkGray, range: range)
                                string.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(25.0)), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.length))
                                let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                                paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
                                string.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.length))

                            }
                            print ("--------------------------------------------")

                        }

                    }
                    self.textView.attributedText = string
                } else {
                    print("detectedText is empty")
                }
            }
        }
    }



    func getWordAtPosition( pos: CGPoint, in textview: UITextView) -> String {
        //Eleminer le balancement du scroll - eliminate scroll offset
     //   var pos = pos
    //    pos.y += tv.contentOffset.y
        //Position du text tapé au point - get location in text from textposition at point
        let tapPos = textview.closestPosition(to: pos)
        //Avoir le mot tapé dans la position du point - fetch the word at this position (or nil, if not available)
        if let wr = textview.tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(tapPos!, with: .word, inDirection: UITextLayoutDirection.right.rawValue) {
            print(pos)
            return textview.text(in: wr)!
        }else{
            return ""
        }

    }
}
```

When I run my app on the simulator, I select a verse and it's going great.

**Normal Use:**

[image: Normal Use]

The problem is with words that appear more than once. For example, for the word "الرحمن" which is found twice, regardless of whether I select the first or the second one, the verse that gets highlighted is always the first one.

[image: Problem]

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `range(of:)` returns the first match only. You have to loop to do it, or use a NSRegularExpression that find all occurrences...

Comment: What do you mean by loop? I fetched all the textView text

Comment: @Larme can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want to highlight the entire verse when the user selects a particular word in that verse.

The problem in your logic is that you determine the word that the user has selected, but that word is not necessarily unique, so when you search for this word (with `textView.text.range(of: detectedText)`), you get back the first result, which may or may not be the one the user actually selected.

One potential solution, if the tokenizer is correctly understanding your text,  is to use a different `TextGranularity` when determining the user's selection. Instead of:

```
textview.tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(tapPos!, with: .word, inDirection: UITextLayoutDirection.right.rawValue)
```

you could try:

```
textview.tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(tapPos!, with: .sentence, inDirection: UITextLayoutDirection.right.rawValue)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't do the thing"? Does the behavior of your app change it all? Is there an error message? We need more information.

Comment: the behaviour of the app still the same